# C++ header #define Function(x) ('ABC\0' | ('0'+(x &0xFF)))

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header

I find this definition in a C++ header

```
#define Function(x) ('ABC\0' | ('0'+(x & 0 x FF)))
```

What does it mean?

Comment: It's an example of what happens if you write code while being completely drunk.

Answer (score 1):

As, you just have quoted a line from the header file, it will show errors if you try to run it. 
However, I can explain you what does it mean,

If you call `Function(x)` any where your program, it will be replaced by `'ABC\0' | ('0'+(x & 0 x FF))`

for example,
if you write this

```
int main(){
    if (Function('DEF'))
        cout << "True" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

it will be replaced by the following code if the second x is multiplier,

```
int main(){
    if ('ABC\0' | ('0' + ('DEF' & 0 x FF)))
        cout << "True" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/17812/) for better understanding.